# Why am I able to modify a variable out of scope with a destructive method?

Tags: ruby

```
class PassByValueScopeConfusion

  def does_not_modify(s)
    s = "DIFFERENT"
  end

  def does_modify(s)
    s.upcase!
  end

end

obj = PassByValueScopeConfusion.new

some_string = "abcdefg"

# does not change the value of some_string
obj.does_not_modify(some_string)

# changes the value of some_string
obj.does_modify(some_string)
```

I'm passing a string to a method that calls a destructive method on the passed in string and somehow, the original variable, "some_string" is modified. If I'm able to modify the "some_string" variable outside of scope with a destructive method, is there a way to do it with an assignment operator (other than calling the replace method)?

**EDIT** Why would Ruby allow for modifying a variable outside of scope with the destructive operator if it doesn't allow it with an assignment operator?

Comment: No, because one modifies a reference value, and one modifies object properties.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between those two cases.

```
s.upcase!
```

This means "modify state of object to which reference s is pointing".

```
s = "DIFFERENT"
```

This, on the other hand, means "make reference to object s point to a completely different object" (or "bind name s to another object" if you prefer). New object `s` is created that shadows outer `s`. There's no way you can modify outer object in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a reference that points to the string object.

So in the does_not_modify example, when called, s contains a pointer to some memory address that contains the string "abcdefg". You then change the value of the reference s to point to a new, different location in memory that holds the new string "DIFFERENT". The caller code however still continues to point to the original location of the original string "abcdefg"

In the does_modify example, s contains a pointer to some memory address that contains the string "abcdefg". The upcase function modifies this part of memory directly and changes each character to "ABCDEFG". The calling code points to this same memory address, and hence the changes are persisted after the function returns.

Comment: So the assignment operator doesn't change where the calling code points to, but the destructive operator does. What is the point of this design? It seems to be counter intuitive that I can change a variable out of scope with the destructive methods.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would Ruby allow for modifying a variable outside of scope

It doesn't. You don't modify the variable, you are modifying the object the variable points to.